# The total reputation gained from a user with an answer should not have a custom background

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, reputation-history

Looking at this [account's reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635654/cygnusx1?tab=reputation) because another question on meta, I noticed the total reputation for a question uses a custom background; it seems like the user got his reputation increased only because a bounty.

[image: screenshot]

Really, the reputation gain is not just because the bounty.

[image: screenshot]

In the specific case, to be useful, the background should use two colors: one for the accepted answer, and one for the bounty.

It makes sense to use a custom background for the entry, but it doesn't make sense to use a custom background for the total reputation gained with a question. The total reputation gained in a day doesn't use a custom background; the total reputation gained with a question should not have a different background too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's explicitly intentional behavior, so you know there was a bounty or accept affecting that number (unless you expanded each one, how would you know?).

It's behaving as designed.

Comment: In the specific case, the background should have two colors, because there is also an accepted answer. That information is not being given, and I should expand the entry to notice there is also an accepted answer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - bounty trumps accepted answers, as they give (minimum 50) more reputation, so they're by definition a bigger component of any summed up number on a post than an accepted answer is.  2 colors isn't reasonable, so the more important one wins, this is also `[status-bydesign]`.